# props being mutated in vue js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

On running my vue file I get the following console error, am new to the vue programming and trying to use syncfusion UI component to print a grid.

```
Prop being mutated: "hierarchyPrintMode"
```

Here is my code, where to add the computed property since i dont have any props and i couldn't understand the solution as listed [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated).

here is the hosted app,
https://codesandbox.io/s/printing-grid-wqrgz

Comment: show a template

Comment: @Anatoly Added the template also.

Comment: Add hierarchyPrintMode: 'All' to a data section, pass it to a ejs-grid like this hierarchyPrintMode:="hierarchyPrintMode" and ten in a code just change this.hierarchyPrintMode to anything you need.

Comment: @Anatoly please elaborate your suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add hierarchyPrintMode: 'All' to a data section, pass it to a ejs-grid like this hierarchyPrintMode:="hierarchyPrintMode" and then in a code just change this.hierarchyPrintMode to anything you need

Comment: you have two assigns at one line. Can you remove one of them to find what assign is causing the error?

Comment: when i try to assign the hierarchyPrintMode for the first grid and its child grid, the hierachyPrintMode property is mutated, since I want to apply that property to both the grids at the same time.

Comment: Just try to assign to one of them for research purposes

Comment: I tried to assign only to parent grid but still the same error.

Comment: so doing this.hierarchyPrintMode = <HierarchyGridPrintMode>element.innerHTML also gives you the same error?

Comment: Can you temporarily remove a child grid and check if the error still remains?

Comment: Okay wait let me host this in stackblitz and share you the project.

Comment: please take a look at this app in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/printing-grid-wqrgz

Comment: hey anatoly, did you look into the codesanbox sample??

Comment: It does not work because of some errors that are not related to your code or maybe just misconfigured.